# Why to install npm package globally?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

What are some reasons or considerations for installing an npm package globally instead of locally in a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install without the -g option, the package will be copied only to the node_modules folder inside your project directory.

The global installation copies all the files to a place where node can access from anywhere.

```
npm install -g my_lib
```

Comment: thank you for your kind comments, can I imagine it like this: if I install a certain package globally, then I can reuse that package in various projects. If I am wrong, then what it means "node can access from anywhere" doesn't it mean reuse a package. I really hope for your reply:)

Comment: Of course you are right. You can call it "reusing".

Answer (score 8):

[From this post](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-packages-local-global):

> The main difference between local and global packages is this:
>
> - **local packages** are installed in the directory where you run `npm install <package-name>`, and they are put in the `node_modules` folder under this directory
> - **global packages** are all put in a single place in your system (exactly where depends on your setup), regardless of where you run `npm install -g <package-name>`
>
> In general, **all packages should be installed locally**.
>
> This makes sure you can have dozens of applications in your computer, all running a different version of each package if needed.
>
> Updating a global package would make all your projects use the new release, and as you can imagine this might cause nightmares in terms of maintenance, as some packages might break compatibility with further dependencies, and so on.
>
> All projects have their own local version of a package, even if this might appear like a waste of resources, it’s minimal compared to the possible negative consequences.
>
> A package **should be installed globally** when it provides an executable command that you run from the shell (CLI), and it’s reused across projects.

Answer (score -1):

A good source to this answer is in the npm documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally)

General rule that I use is that if the package can be used in multiple projects then I will apply the package globally.  Eslint is a good example of this.